# Parsing a list out of lists using Java Streams

Tags: java, list, java-stream, collectors

I have a list of products. Each product holds another list of ingredients.
How can I use Streams in order to get a list of all ingredients from all products?

```
products.stream()
        .map(Product::getIngredients())
        .filter(i -> !i.isEmpty())
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Above the code as far as I got, so far I'm just getting a list with sublists...

What's the right way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Look at `Stream.flatMap`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: thanks for your quick answer, it worked :)

Answer (score 7):

Just use `flatMap` :

```
products.stream()
        .flatMap(product -> product.getIngredients().stream())
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: That'd have to be `.flatMap(product -> product.getIngredients().stream())`

Comment: Or `.map(Product::getIngredients).flatMap(List::stream)`.

Comment: @SchiduLuca you btw need to explicitly tell OP that `distinct` requires hashcode/equals overridden... which you don't know if it's an option or not. otherwise plus one

Comment: @Eugene It's worth a mention perhaps, but it's not at all relevant to the question or answer.